# Enable or disable column based on other column

Tags: java, sharepoint

I have Application with 3 columns

Result - Radio button pass and Fail 
IF Fail - Radio Button Minor and  Major
Be Specific -  Multiple Choice - Active X control/ Browser/ Display / Others

I want to disable If fail and Be specific if Result is selected pass.

How can I do it

Thanks
Kundan

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your looking at a SharePoint list column?

The only way to do this that I can think of is to develop a custom field type that seeks out the value of other fields and deccides whether or not to render.

This [how-to on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919.aspx) should help you achieve your goal.

There is no "out of the box" way to achive your goal. You must write code to accomplish this.